# How to include column header with uuencode in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, uuencode

Im using uuencode in unix shell scripting but im unable to get the Column header included in the extraction in email.

file1.csv
Col1 col2

1. Meghan
2. ```
   Sarah
   ```

Command I have used:
(Cat emailbody.txt; uuencode file1.csv file1.csv) | mailx -s "subject" email@.com

Attachment in email.

1. Meghan
2. Sarah

I need the Col1 and Col2 column header as well

Comment: What kind of column header do you imagine for a uuencoded file? "`data`"?

Comment: I have edited and added more details please check

Comment: The post could use some more formatting, but it sounds like you're saying that the "col1 col2" is in file1.csv, but after you uuencode it, the header disappears when ... doing what -- viewing the attachment later?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992857/2836621

Comment: @Jeff schaller ... yes the header disappears after I use uuencode.  So in the email the attachment is without a header

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add header to the SQL output is i.e., add `SET HEADER ON` ,`SET PAGESIZE 500000` to your `.sql` file. you can set `pagesize` to the max number based on your output.